# Initiating Oauth process in BigCommerce

Tags: oauth, bigcommerce

I had been authorizing bigcommerce user via legacy API method.
Now we are planing to start authorization using Oauth process.

Till now i have created an app in Developer portal- got client id and secret. Added callback url

My question is How can i initiate Oauth process for bigcommerce users from my web app?
I am unable to find this in Docs.

Like for other gateways like Shopify, we need to hit an url with client ID, then it used to redirect to login url.

Comment: Are you trying to authorize bigcommerce merchants or merchants' customers?

Comment: @Alyss Bigcommerce merchants- to import store orders

Comment: When the oAuth app is first being installed, you should receive a callback URI that contains client information: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback

Comment: @Alyss This will only work if my App is present in Bicommerce app store. But my question is how can i initiate oauth process from my App(not listed in app store). Doesn't Bigcommerce provide Oauth like Shopify?

Comment: You don't have to have it as a submitted app in the app store. You can leave it as a draft app that can only be privately installed. This is how we provide oAuth credentials today. We are working on improvements.